# magento 1.9.3 based ecommerce site product selection to checkout in single page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

Is it possible to create a single page magento e-Commerce website?

Mainly displaying the products, cart and checkout everything on the same page.

Comment: Depends on you and number of products ... but yes it is possible

Comment: In my experience, there is no "cannot" in Magento. Magento architecture is highly extendable and thus everything is possible with Magento. Only thing is, you need to find a proper developer to do that :)

Comment: @RajeevKTomy, is right..you need  to find out proper developer and development logic

Comment: @Gopal Patel can u plz help me out we have only 4 products. plz guide me how to do. i'm not very very use to with magento. give me ur mail id will share html code. we want to convert this html code to mangto

Comment: @AnoopShakya as suggest by benmark in answer use angular frontend and use magento rest api

Comment: @GopalPatel plz open the mentiond link http://development.easystartup.org/modafinil/demo/product-selection.html we acctually want that page in magento. or can u plz send me a simple document guide instructions so that i can read and do accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. The [Grokking Magento](https://shop.vinaikopp.com/grokking-magento/#!/home) website is an angular frontend running on top of Magento.